# Compress a mysql partition

Tags: mysql, compression, partitioning

I have a table that is partitioned by a timestamp into a separate partition for each day.

During each day around a billion events are received.  Each event is tagged with an object, and the business logic needs all the events for an object to decide what to do with them.  So the system has a big table with one row per object (which is just hundreds of millions of rows per day), and these events are concatenated into an 'event buffer' mediumtext.

One row per object works really well.  It is very fast and suitable for our business logic and reporting to consume.  Once upon a time we started with an event table and joining instead, and it was far too slow.

After 5 days no more events will be received for an object.  At that point, if we haven't had terminating events, our system adds our own 'timed out' event to the buffer.

We are doing a lot of business logic as events for an object are received, and we have a bool to flag which objects have no final event etc.

Although the "online" system only wants 5 days of object events, the reporting system wants a year's worth.

I want partitions over 5 days old to be compressed.  I can run a cron-job to trigger this.

The current approach is: have another table, with identical schema and partitioning like the online table but row_format=compressed.  Then each day, create a new table like these table but without partitioning.  First we `ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION` to swap-out the 5-days-old partition.  Then we insert this into the new table.

There are two problems with the current approach: 1) that reporting tools have to scan two separate tables, and 2) that there is a race condition when objects are in neither of the main tables.

Is it possible to `ALTER` the `row_format` for an individual existing partition?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot compress individual partitions.  The basic attributes of the table are uniform across all partitions.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the table size, and further discussion of "why" you want to compress.  There may be a workaround that achieves a similar function.

**Reporting**

"Reports" usually need "summary" information, not all the raw data.  So...  Summarize the data each day (or hour, or whatever) and put the summary into a much smaller table.  Then throw away the raw data.

If you are concerned about need the raw data at a later data, then save the logs, compressed, in regular files.  Sure, it will be some extra work to pull up old data.  But there are trade offs.

This also solves the interference -- different table, smaller table.

For summarizing, I usually do it periodically, but it could be done as data is inserted into the raw ("Fact") table.  See [*Summary tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) and [*High speed ingestion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).  In the later link, it explains a way to gather data in a "staging table", massague it, send it to the Fact table, Normalization tables (which perhaps you don't have) and do the incremental summarization.

Your raw data might be partitioned in 6-hour chunks: `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))`.  30 partitions is a pretty good number (a compromise).  The Summary table(s) might need to be partitioned.  Consider 12 or 52 if you are purging after a year.  (Actually 14 or 54; see the links for why.)

**Migrating a partition**

Suppose you could move the 6-day-old partition to another, more compressed, table; and use a `VIEW` in front of a `UNION` to mask the existence of the split?

If you have 5.7, it is pretty easy to "export a tablespace"; this turn the partition into a table.  Then, you could either import it into another partitioned table (which does not seem very useful, unless it is somehow compressed), or otherwise transform the data to shrink it.

**Manual compression**

For large text columns, I recommend compressing in the client, storing into a `BLOB` (instead of `TEXT`), and uncompressing on the way out.  This saves disk space (3x for typical English, code, xml, etc) and bandwidth (to/from client -- especially handy if the client and server are distant).

**Database API Layer**

You have users issuing SQL queries?  You should seriously consider providing a simple layer between the clients and the database.  With that, you can hide view, union, compress, two tables, etc.  And you can change things without making the customers make changes.  Be sure to create an API that understands the client and feels more 'generic'.  `GetObject(1234)` does whatever SQL is needed, then returns "object #1234" in some agreed-upon format (JSON, XML, PHP structure, whatever).

Comment: Thx.  Have added some background.

Comment: Sigh.  My reports want the object-per-row data.  The data is taking a few GB per day and compressing it gets it small enough to fit 1 year on a single big box I have.  But compressing the partitions that the online system is building hurts its performance too much.  Hence wanting the best of both worlds where I compress the partitions I'm not going to write to again because they are more than 5 days old.  As soon as I have more than one table my users have to know to query more than one table.  I thought about a view union but the temporary table makes that hard.

Comment: I added more thoughts.

Comment: Yeah it seems its not possible.  It would be so nice to be able to have one table that holds all the objects, one per row, even for objects that are less than 5 days old and may still be receiving events.  This is easy for the various reporting tools to consume.  But it seems you can't selectively compress partitions, so its a no-go.

Comment: "Receiving events"??  Are there two parts of an object -- the static, unchanging, columns, plus other columns that reflect the events?  What fraction of the row (object) is devoted to each?  I'm wondering if a vertical partitioning is useful.